# How to convert java list to array in scala?

Tags: java, arrays, scala, list, collections

How to convert java.util.list[POJO] to Scala array[POJO]?
I tried list.toArray method but  it gives array[object].
Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Can you tell me the structure of your pojo?

Comment: Try importing javaConverters and do list.asScala it should work

Comment: Yeah..It works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create the target array first, and provide it as input for the `toArray` method:

```
list.toArray(Array.ofDim[POJO](list.size))
```

This API shifts all the problems with array instantiation from the `toArray` method to you, so it is your responsibility to make sure that `POJO` is either something concrete, or to provide a `ClassTag`.

---

You could also do the conversion in two steps, first using `asScala` from [`JavaConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

and then invoking `.toArray` from the Scala API (unlike Java's API, it preserves the type):

```
list.asScala.toArray
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code works for me:

### applcation.conf

mydata.crypto {

```
ciphers = [

           "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

           "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

           "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

          ]

 protocols = [

               "TLSv1.2"

             ]

   }
```

---

### Sample code in scala
Reading as List:

val ciphersList = config.getStringList("mydata.crypto.ciphers")

val protocolsList = config.getStringList("mydata.crypto.protocols")

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val enableCiphersList = ciphersList.asScala.toArray

val enableProtocolsList = protocolsList.asScala.toArray

Now we can see "enableCiphersList" and "enableProtocolsList" are Array of Strings type.